# How to create an object that can modify its original function call

Tags: javascript, button, canvas

I am trying to create a button object which can run a class function (show() in this case) that will change the button's color. The problem is I can only do this by calling show() repeatedly each time the color changes. The result is a ton of buttons being drawn on the screen, but I would like to only draw the button once. Is there a way around this? (Note: I have the button x position increasing to show the buttons being created)

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("JScanvas"),
  c = canvas.getContext("2d");

let mousePosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
// ignore, a few functions I might need for this to run

function buildRect(fillColor, outlineColor, outlineSize, x, y, w, h) {
  if (fillColor && outlineColor) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(x, y, w, h);
    c.fillStyle = fillColor;
    c.fill();
    c.lineWidth = outlineSize;
    c.strokeStyle = outlineColor;
    c.stroke();
  } else if (fillColor && !outlineColor) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(x, y, w, h);
    c.fillStyle = fillColor;
    c.fill();
  } else if (!fillColor && outlineColor) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(x, y, w, h);
    c.lineWidth = outlineSize;
    c.strokeStyle = outlineColor;
    c.stroke();
  }
}

function write(str, x, y, color, txtSize, font) {
  let size = txtSize.toString();
  c.font = size + "px" + " " + font;
  c.fillStyle = color;
  c.fillText(str, x, y);
}
// end of useless functions

class button {
  // mouse is {canvs: canvas, mClicked: t/f, mPosition: mousePosition{x, y}}
  constructor(name, order, btnColor, x, y, w, h, txtColor, txtSize, m, f) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = order;
    this.btnColor = btnColor;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.txtColor = txtColor;
    this.txtSize = txtSize;
    this.m = m;
    this.f = f;

    //change color when mouse over button
    this.m.canvs.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
      console.log("hello there");

      if (this.x < this.m.mPosition.x && this.m.mPosition.x < this.x + this.w && this.y < this.m.mPosition.y && this.m.mPosition.y < this.y + this.h) {

        if (this.btnColor[0] != "grey") {
          this.btnColor[0] = "grey";
          this.x += 50;
          this.show();
        } else {
          this.btnColor[0] = "red";
          this.x += 50;
          this.show();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  show() {
    if (!this.btnColor[0] && !this.btnColor[0]) {
      buildRect("transparent", false, 1, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    } else if (!this.btnColor[0]) {
      buildRect(false, this.btnColor[1], 1, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    } else if (!this.btnColor[1]) {
      buildRect(this.btnColor[0], false, 1, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    } else {
      buildRect(this.btnColor[0], this.btnColor[1], 1, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }
    c.fillStyle = this.txtColor;
    let theString = String(this.txtSize) + "px Arial";
    c.font = theString;
    let width = Math.round(c.measureText(c.fillText(this.name, -1000, 0)).width);

    if (width > this.w) {
      let center = this.x + (this.w / 2);
      let newSize = this.w / width;
      c.font = String(this.txtSize * newSize);
      let newWidth = Math.round(newSize * width);
      c.textAlign = "center";
      c.textBaseline = "middle";
      c.fillText(this.name, this.x + (this.w / 2), this.y + (this.h / 2));

    } else {
      c.textAlign = "center";
      c.textBaseline = "middle";
      c.fillText(this.name, this.x + (this.w / 2), this.y + (this.h / 2));
    }
  }

  clickButton(mouseX, mouseY) {
    if (mouseX >= this.x && mouseX <= this.x + this.w && mouseY >= this.y && mouseY <= this.y + this.h) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  runf() {
    this.f();
  }
}

//getting mouse position 

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  let r = getMousePos(canvas, event);
  mousePosition.x = r.x, mousePosition.y = r.y;
});

let mouse = {
  canvs: canvas,
  mClicked: false,
  mPosition: mousePosition
};

//button object to call: ("red" is the color of the button I am trying to change to grey)
let cookie = new button("cookie", 1, ["red", false], 50, 100, 150, 50, "black", 30, mouse, 2);
cookie.show();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Playground</title>

</head>

<body>

  <canvas width="1500" height="1500" id="JScanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should remember the old button position, so you can remove it before drawing the new button.

Comment: Maybe you should implement the button as a Sprite, so you can animate it rather than just drawing new rectangles.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting. If I save the old position, how would I remove the old rectangle given it was called in the original show()? I could do a sprite I suppose, but is there no other way?

Comment: You could draw it again using the background color, which makes it go away.

Comment: @Barmar Drawing it as the background color does make it disappear on the screen, but I think the code is still running. It continues to build excess waste.

Comment: I don't really know much about using canvas, but it doesn't look like it "does" anything. It's just a rectangle that you've drawn in the canvas.

Comment: I really think you should look at sprites. That seems perfect for what you're doing.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I'll look into them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have over complicated your code...

Here is a simple example where we change the color when the mouse is over the rectangle

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
let c = canvas.getContext("2d");

class button {
  constructor(color, x, y, w, h) {
    this.color = color;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }

  draw(mouse) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    if (mouse.x >= this.x && mouse.x <= this.x + this.w &&
      mouse.y >= this.y && mouse.y <= this.y + this.h) {
      c.fillStyle = "gray";
    } else {
      c.fillStyle = this.color;
    }
    c.fill();
  }
}

function getMousePos(evt) {
  if (!evt) return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { x: evt.clientX - rect.left, y: evt.clientY - rect.top };
}

let buttons = []
buttons.push(new button("red", 50, 100, 40, 20))
buttons.push(new button("blue", 100, 50, 40, 20))

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mainDraw);

function mainDraw(evt) {
  let mouse = getMousePos(evt)
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.draw(mouse)
  })
}

mainDraw()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

As you can see there is only one addEventListener and it is outside the class button, the logic is simple, we clean the entire canvas and draw everything on every event... that is how games do it, I'm sure that will work for what you are doing too.